# Есть ли возможность печатать apple эмодзи с помощью библиотеки emoji?

Tags: python, emoji

Мне просто нужно печатать эмодзи флагов стран, а у набора эмодзи microsoft там нет флагов а только аббревиатуры типа: США - us, Россия - ru и тп.

Answer (score 0):

Нету, вот вся база: https://carpedm20.github.io/emoji/
В библиотеке только смайлики microsoft